# Discord Java Bot (with Javacord library) can't play music on Raspberry

Tags: java, discord, bots, raspberry-pi3, lavaplayer

I'm trying to create a **Discord Bot** with Java, using **Javacord** and **Lavaplayer** librairies, to play music on voice channels, but I'm having problem deploying my app on my Raspberry and I don't understand where the problem comes from.

When I run the app from my Eclipse (on Windows 10) the bot works perfectly and plays music on Discord (via YouTube URL - hard coded), but when I try to use it from my Raspberry and ask same command, the bot connects in voice channel but no sound is played !

I tried several things by myself (like, heard about Native Library so I added '/natives/linux-arm/libconnector.so' in classpath). I didn't see errors in logs neither. I couldn't find the reason on my own, so I need help figuring out where the problem's coming from :(

P.S: I don't know if the issue come from Java code or Raspberry configurations/specifications

**Project sources:**

Application.java

```
package fr.exec;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.javacord.api.DiscordApi;
import org.javacord.api.DiscordApiBuilder;

/**
 * Classe Application
 * 
 * @author Jo44
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 30/03/2021
 */
public class Application {

    /**
     * Attributs
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);

    // Application
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Launch Bot
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        DiscordApi api = new DiscordApiBuilder().addListener(new MessageListener())
                .setToken([TOKEN]).login().join();
        logger.info("Bot is online & ready");

    }

}
```

MessageListener.java

```
package fr.exec;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.javacord.api.audio.AudioSource;
import org.javacord.api.entity.channel.ServerVoiceChannel;
import org.javacord.api.entity.user.User;
import org.javacord.api.event.message.MessageCreateEvent;
import org.javacord.api.listener.message.MessageCreateListener;

import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.AudioLoadResultHandler;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.AudioPlayer;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.AudioPlayerManager;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.youtube.YoutubeAudioSourceManager;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.tools.FriendlyException;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.AudioPlaylist;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.AudioTrack;

/**
 * Classe MessageListener
 * 
 * @author Jo44
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 30/03/2021
 */
public class MessageListener implements MessageCreateListener {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MessageListener.class);

    /**
     * Message Listener
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageCreate(MessageCreateEvent event) {
        String cmd = event.getMessageContent().toLowerCase();
        if (cmd.equals("!ping")) {
            // Ping-pong
            cmdPing(event);
        } else if (cmd.equals("!sound")) {
            // Sound
            cmdSound(event);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Commande !ping
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    private static void cmdPing(MessageCreateEvent event) {
        // Message
        String message = "Pong!";
        // Return message
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(message);
        // Log
        logger.info(message);
    }

    /**
     * Commande !sound
     * 
     * @param event
     * @param cmd
     */
    private static void cmdSound(MessageCreateEvent event) {
        // Get User
        User user = event.getMessage().getAuthor().asUser().get();
        // Get VoiceChannel where User is
        long userVoiceChannelId = 0;
        List<ServerVoiceChannel> voiceChannels = event.getServer().get().getVoiceChannels();
        for (ServerVoiceChannel chan : voiceChannels) {
            if (user.isConnected(chan)) {
                userVoiceChannelId = chan.getId();
            }
        }
        // If User is connected
        if (userVoiceChannelId != 0) {

            try {

                // Javacord Wiki Part :
                // https://javacord.org/wiki/advanced-topics/playing-audio.html#playing-music

                // Do stuff

                ServerVoiceChannel channel = event.getApi().getServerVoiceChannelById(userVoiceChannelId).get();
                channel.connect().thenAccept(audioConnection -> {

                    // Create a player manager
                    AudioPlayerManager playerManager = new DefaultAudioPlayerManager();
                    playerManager.registerSourceManager(new YoutubeAudioSourceManager());
                    AudioPlayer player = playerManager.createPlayer();

                    // Create an audio source and add it to the audio connection's queue
                    AudioSource source = new LavaplayerAudioSource(event.getApi(), player);
                    audioConnection.setAudioSource(source);

                    // You can now use the AudioPlayer like you would normally do with Lavaplayer, e.g.,
                    playerManager.loadItem("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GX8Hg6kWQYI", new AudioLoadResultHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void trackLoaded(AudioTrack track) {
                            player.playTrack(track);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void playlistLoaded(AudioPlaylist playlist) {
                            for (AudioTrack track : playlist.getTracks()) {
                                player.playTrack(track);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void noMatches() {
                            // Notify the user that we've got nothing
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void loadFailed(FriendlyException throwable) {
                            // Notify the user that everything exploded
                        }
                    });

                }).exceptionally(e -> {
                    // Failed to connect to voice channel (no permissions?)
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                });

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error(ex.getMessage());
                logger.error(ex.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

LavaplayerAudioSource.java

```
package fr.exec;

import org.javacord.api.DiscordApi;
import org.javacord.api.audio.AudioSource;
import org.javacord.api.audio.AudioSourceBase;

import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.AudioPlayer;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.playback.AudioFrame;

public class LavaplayerAudioSource extends AudioSourceBase {

    private final AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
    private AudioFrame lastFrame;

    /**
     * Creates a new lavaplayer audio source.
     *
     * @param api
     *            A discord api instance.
     * @param audioPlayer
     *            An audio player from Lavaplayer.
     */
    public LavaplayerAudioSource(DiscordApi api, AudioPlayer audioPlayer) {
        super(api);
        this.audioPlayer = audioPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getNextFrame() {
        if (lastFrame == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return applyTransformers(lastFrame.getData());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasFinished() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNextFrame() {
        lastFrame = audioPlayer.provide();
        return lastFrame != null;
    }

    @Override
    public AudioSource copy() {
        return new LavaplayerAudioSource(getApi(), audioPlayer);
    }

}
```

**Project Download:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10-AFPNdJBkPhpSH-PtgiINloNP9VFRIo/view?usp=sharing

**Debug Logs:**

```
2021-03-30 10:04:28 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Creating shard 1 of 1
2021-03-30 10:04:30 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Trying to send GET request to https://discord.com/api/v6/gateway
2021-03-30 10:04:31 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent GET request to https://discord.com/api/v6/gateway and received status code 200 with body {"url": "wss://gateway.discord.gg"}
2021-03-30 10:04:31 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Calculated an offset of -540 to the Discord time.
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Received HELLO packet
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending identify packet
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Queued lifecycle frame for sending with priority: WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":0}")
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:48) - Queued lifecycle frame for sending without priority: WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=252,Payload="{"op":2,"d":{"token":"Bot **********","compress":true,"large_threshold":250,"properties":{"$os":"Linux","$browser":"Javacord","$device":"Javacord","$referrer":"","$referring_domain":""},"intents":32509}}")
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: false, packet: {"op":1,"d":0})
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending priority lifecycle frame WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":0}")
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:48) - Sending frame WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=252,Payload="{"op":2,"d":{"token":"Bot **********","compress":true,"large_threshold":250,"properties":{"$os":"Linux","$browser":"Javacord","$device":"Javacord","$referrer":"","$referring_domain":""},"intents":32509}}")
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: false, packet: {"t":null,"s":null,"op":11,"d":null}). Took 125 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:04:32 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Received READY packet
2021-03-30 10:04:33 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Trying to send GET request to https://discord.com/api/v6/oauth2/applications/@me
2021-03-30 10:04:33 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent GET request to https://discord.com/api/v6/oauth2/applications/@me and received status code 200 with body {"id": "[BOT ID]", "name": "[BOT NAME]", "icon": null, "description": "", "summary": "", "hook": true, "bot_public": true, "bot_require_code_grant": false, "verify_key": "[KEY]", "owner": {"id": "[OWNER ID]", "username": "[OWNER NAME]", "avatar": "[AVATAR]", "discriminator": "7460", "public_flags": 0, "flags": 0}, "team": null}
2021-03-30 10:04:33 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Calculated an offset of -366 to the Discord time.
2021-03-30 10:04:33 | INFO  | (Application.java:29) - Bot is online & ready
2021-03-30 10:04:41 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Trying to send POST request to https://discord.com/api/v6/channels/[CHAN_ID]/messages with body {"content":"Pong!","tts":false,"mentions":[]}
2021-03-30 10:04:41 | INFO  | (MessageListener.java:60) - Pong!
2021-03-30 10:04:41 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent POST request to https://discord.com/api/v6/channels/[CHAN_ID]/messages and received status code 200 with body {"id": "[ID]", "type": 0, "content": "Pong!", "channel_id": "[CHAN ID]", "author": {"id": "[BOT ID]", "username": "[BOT NAME]", "avatar": null, "discriminator": "3473", "public_flags": 0, "bot": true}, "attachments": [], "embeds": [], "mentions": [], "mention_roles": [], "pinned": false, "mention_everyone": false, "tts": false, "timestamp": "2021-03-30T08:04:41.469000+00:00", "edited_timestamp": null, "flags": 0, "referenced_message": null}
2021-03-30 10:05:02 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending VOICE_STATE_UPDATE packet for ServerVoiceChannel (id: [CHAN ID], name: [CHAN NAME]) on Server (id: [SERVER ID], name: [SERVER NAME])
2021-03-30 10:05:02 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Queued non-lifecycle frame for sending without priority: WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=116,Payload="{"op":4,"d":{"guild_id":"[GUILD ID]","channel_id":"[CHAN ID]","self_mute":false,"self_deaf":false}}")
2021-03-30 10:05:02 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending frame WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=116,Payload="{"op":4,"d":{"guild_id":"[GUILD ID]","channel_id":"[CHAN ID]","self_mute":false,"self_deaf":false}}")
2021-03-30 10:05:02 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Received all information required to connect to voice channel ServerVoiceChannel (id: [CHAN ID], name: [CHAN NAME])
2021-03-30 10:05:02 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Trying to connect to websocket wss://eu-central4013.discord.media:443?v=4
2021-03-30 10:05:03 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Received HELLO packet for AudioConnection (channel: ServerVoiceChannel (id: [CHAN ID], name: [CHAN NAME]), sessionId: [SESSION ID], endpoint: eu-central4013.discord.media:443)
2021-03-30 10:05:03 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending voice identify packet for AudioConnection (channel: ServerVoiceChannel (id: [CHAN ID], name: [CHAN NAME]), sessionId: [SESSION ID], endpoint: eu-central4013.discord.media:443)
2021-03-30 10:05:03 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":1636756561})
2021-03-30 10:05:03 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Received READY packet for AudioConnection (channel: ServerVoiceChannel (id: [CHAN ID], name: [CHAN NAME]), sessionId: [SESSION ID], endpoint: eu-central4013.discord.media:443)
2021-03-30 10:05:03 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":1636756561}). Took 71 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:05:13 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Queued lifecycle frame for sending with priority: WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":9}")
2021-03-30 10:05:13 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending priority lifecycle frame WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":9}")
2021-03-30 10:05:13 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: false, packet: {"op":1,"d":9})
2021-03-30 10:05:13 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: false, packet: {"t":null,"s":null,"op":11,"d":null}). Took 121 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:05:16 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":1340128277})
2021-03-30 10:05:16 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":1340128277}). Took 42 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:05:30 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":1763156639})
2021-03-30 10:05:30 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":1763156639}). Took 36 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:05:44 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":913943586})
2021-03-30 10:05:44 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":913943586}). Took 48 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:05:54 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Queued lifecycle frame for sending with priority: WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":9}")
2021-03-30 10:05:54 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending priority lifecycle frame WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":9}")
2021-03-30 10:05:54 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: false, packet: {"op":1,"d":9})
2021-03-30 10:05:54 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: false, packet: {"t":null,"s":null,"op":11,"d":null}). Took 137 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:05:58 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":1280403229})
2021-03-30 10:05:58 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":1280403229}). Took 49 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:06:11 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":1680218539})
2021-03-30 10:06:11 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":1680218539}). Took 47 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:06:25 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":1171436739})
2021-03-30 10:06:25 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":1171436739}). Took 35 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:06:36 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Queued lifecycle frame for sending with priority: WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":9}")
2021-03-30 10:06:36 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: false, packet: {"op":1,"d":9})
2021-03-30 10:06:36 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sending priority lifecycle frame WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=14,Payload="{"op":1,"d":9}")
2021-03-30 10:06:36 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: false, packet: {"t":null,"s":null,"op":11,"d":null}). Took 121 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:06:39 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":514863837})
2021-03-30 10:06:39 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":514863837}). Took 39 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:06:53 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Sent heartbeat (voice: true, packet: {"op":3,"d":402475903})
2021-03-30 10:06:53 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Heartbeat ACK received (voice: true, packet: {"op":6,"d":402475903}). Took 43 ms to receive ACK
2021-03-30 10:07:00 | DEBUG | (PrivacyProtectionLogger.java:51) - Queued lifecycle frame for sending without priority: WebSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=CLOSE,Length=2,CloseCode=1000,Reason=null)
2021-03-30 11:42:09 | INFO  | (Application.java:29) - Bot is online & ready
2021-03-30 11:42:15 | INFO  | (MessageListener.java:60) - Pong!
```

**Debug Download:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t8xwQcUx5VDpH0OVWxZnJb38eu5vgBpI/view?usp=sharing

**Javacord Wiki:** https://javacord.org/wiki/advanced-topics/playing-audio.html

**Dev Computer:**
*Windows 10 Home - 20H2 -
java version "1.8.0_281" -
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09) -
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)*

**Raspberry Pi 3 Model B:**
*Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch) -
openjdk version "1.8.0_275" -
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-1~deb9u1-b01) -
OpenJDK Client VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)*

Comment: I think this question is OK in general, but you should include the source code in the question itself, not pasting the link to googledrive (same with output logs). Voting to reopen, but please edit the question accordingly. Remember to keep the example [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thx for your comment ! I updated as you advised, I hope it will be enough to re-open my topic, I really need help :(

Comment: I see that the Java minor version is higher on your development computer than your Raspberry (281 -> 275).  I don't know if Java considers the minor version or not when determining forward compatibility.